# How to change the header of a column so i can join it with another data set?

Tags: python, join, merge, geopandas

I'm trying to join a dataset to another so i can perform spatial analysis. Both datasets have columns which can be joined, but one is written in capital letters and the other lowercase. Do I need to change the way the header is written or can I join the columns another way?

```
london = gpd.read_file('https://github.com/cusp-london/Spatial-Data-Analysis/blob/master/LDN-LSOAs.zip?raw=true')
london

lsoa11cd    lsoa11nm    lsoa11nmw   objectid    st_areasha  st_lengths  geometry
0   E01000001   City of London 001A City of London 001A 1   133,320.7689    2,291.8461  POLYGON ((532105.330 182017.386, 532162.728 18...
1   E01000002   City of London 001B City of London 001B 2   226,191.2730    2,433.9601  POLYGON ((532747.048 181793.042, 532671.921 18...
2   E01000003   City of London 001C City of London 001C 3   57,302.9665 1,142.3598  POLYGON ((532135.385 182204.275, 532158.489 18...
3   E01000005   City of London 001E City of London 001E 4   190,738.7605    2,167.8683  POLYGON ((533808.170 180773.910, 533649.287 18...
4   E01000006   Barking and Dagenham 016A   Barking and Dagenham 016A   5   144,195.8469    1,935.5104  POLYGON ((545122.084 184321.013, 545271.951 18...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4830    E01033742   Greenwich 007F  Greenwich 007F  32818   123,309.1855    1,860.3102  POLYGON ((544642.760 179830.773, 544766.392 17...
4831    E01033743   Greenwich 002H  Greenwich 002H  32819   1,004,853.0874  5,237.1802  POLYGON ((546579.271 181103.898, 546687.117 18...
4832    E01033744   Greenwich 007G  Greenwich 007G  32820   152,261.9933    2,149.3709  POLYGON ((544536.564 179453.221, 544602.707 17...
4833    E01033745   Greenwich 002I  Greenwich 002I  32821   558,477.7026    4,193.8283  POLYGON ((546415.827 180158.362, 546320.798 18...
4834    E01033746   Greenwich 038E  Greenwich 038E  32822   128,976.6864    2,367.4053  POLYGON ((538140.138 177319.110, 538129.314 17...
4835 rows × 7 columns

ptal_lsoas

geometry    LSOA11CD    AvPTAI2015  PTAL    PTAIHigh    PTAILow
0   POLYGON ((532105.092 182011.230, 532162.491 18...   E01000001   69.8233 6b  97.4435 35.9190
1   POLYGON ((532746.813 181786.891, 532671.688 18...   E01000002   83.7820 6b  117.9120    66.3503
2   POLYGON ((532135.145 182198.119, 532158.250 18...   E01000003   41.7417 6b  49.5318 37.3635
3   POLYGON ((533807.946 180767.770, 533649.063 18...   E01000005   85.8893 6b  120.8470    45.9168
4   POLYGON ((545122.049 184314.931, 545271.917 18...   E01000006   22.4558 5   34.1054 0.0000
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4830    POLYGON ((544642.680 179824.674, 544766.313 17...   E01033742   3.9532  1b  5.7986  3.0585
4831    POLYGON ((546579.195 181097.813, 546687.036 18...   E01033743   3.8174  1b  14.3944 0.0000
4832    POLYGON ((544536.486 179447.115, 544602.630 17...   E01033744   10.1709 3   23.5689 3.5750
4833    POLYGON ((546415.745 180152.270, 546320.715 18...   E01033745   4.6838  1b  11.4851 0.0000
4834    POLYGON ((538140.000 177313.000, 538129.177 17...   E01033746   18.9882 4   24.1235 14.5436
4835 rows × 6 columns
```

i have also tried to join them via the 'geometry' column but am met with no data showing

```
geo_ptal_lsoas = pd.merge (london, ptal_lsoas, left_on = ['geometry'],
                  right_on = ['geometry'],
                  how = 'inner')

geo_ptal_lsoas

lsoa11cd_x  lsoa11nm_x  lsoa11nmw_x objectid_x  st_areasha_x    st_lengths_x    geometry    lsoa11cd_y  lsoa11nm_y  lsoa11nmw_y objectid_y  st_areasha_y    st_lengths_y    LSOA11CD    AvPTAI2015  PTAL    PTAIHigh    PTAILow
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: you can specify different columns in the merge for `left_on` and `right_on`, so you don't need to change the column names for a join. But it looks like you might be trying to do a spatial join? geopandas doesn't work with two geometry columns in the same dataframe. Can you back up and explain more about what you're trying to do? If you're trying to do a spatial join of these dataframes, e.g. find which polygons in one frame contain specific points in the other, use `geopandas.sjoin` not `pd.merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Covert the columns of your second dataframe to lowercase using:

```
ptal_lsoas.columns = ptal_lsoas.columns.str.lower()
```